# His eyes fell upon - I got it, but

Tags: british-english

Today I've been reading a book and I came across this:
"As he walked across the room, **his eyes fell I upon** the little table on which Marvolo Gaunt’s ring had rested last I time, but the ring was no longer there."

Is it just a mistake and **I** needs to be removed or is it some construction? (British English)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a typographical error.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, possible. But I believe his doubt was genuine in order to know if such a construction does exist in English, in other words, wrt English grammar

Comment: This second _I_ is incorrect also: _the little table on which Marvolo Gaunt’s ring had rested last **I** time_. Is this an official version of the book?

Comment: @user1993 I'm sorry, but even if this were a question based on grammar, and not on a single typographical  episode, the question would still be off topic. The OP (original poster) has not shown a shred of research. In addition,  the grammar is very basic for a site that claims to be for experts, etymologists, and linguists. EDIT: another misplaced pronoun, either the OP is misreading something, or he is reading a bootleg copy :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the 'I' in the sentence you mention is possibly a printing mistake. The correct edition reads -

> As he walked across the room, his eyes ***fell upon*** the little table on
> which Marvolo Gaunt's ring had rested last time, but the ring was no
> longer there
>
> *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 13- THE SECRET RIDDLE*

I am pretty sure a construction like '*fell* [**subject**] *upon*' does not exist in English

Comment: I'm glad you discovered the source.  Given that it's a Harry Potter story, I'm going to assume that the sentence is not about a guy with poorly fitting ocular prosthetics.